# Java: Minimum Depth of Binary search Tree Recursive

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

I am writing the code to calculate minimum depth of binary tree
My solution works well for tree BST if the inputs are 6,4,9,3,5,7,12,2,8
because minimum depth is coming as 3 which is correct.
But when the tree is 3,2 , minimum depth is coming as 1 instead of 2.
My code snippet is:

```
int minimumHeightRec(TreeNode root)
        {
            if(root == null) return 0;
            int left = minimumHeightRec(root.left);
            int right = minimumHeightRec(root.right);
            if(left > right) return right + 1;
            else return left + 1;
        }
```

Comment: When you say "when the tree is 3,2" do you mean the input? 
In that case, the root node will be "3" and the left node will be "2", while the right node will be null; in which case, returning 1 as minimum tree depth is correct.

Comment: yes .....................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is correct. The expected minHeight should be 1 instead of 2.
Consider your example of [3, 2] the BST may have the following form:

```
  3
 /
2
```

looking into `left` of `root` has height of 2: (3) -> (2)

looking into `right` of `root` has height of 1: (3)

You're looking for the minHeight of the BST, so taking the right branch of height `1` is the correct choice.

Note that you may have a different tree form where `2` is the root, but the logic and result will be the same.

Comment: But i solved this question in Leetcode and its showing wrong.   
Refer https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-depth-of-binary-tree/

Comment: I see where the difference is, in the link you provided they define depth down to a leaf nodes which *must* have zero child. Which means in the case of [3, 2] root does not count, since root (3) has a child (2). Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see how the tree you've written, Ling Zhong, has a right branch. There's only one root (3) and one left branch with a leaf (2). There's no right branch.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox I should phrase it better, it's more of looking into `right` of `root`. Please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

- The else is useless because there is a return in the if.
- Some more code (TreeNode class and main) would be usefull.

Comment: The `else` actually improves readability since it makes it explicit under which condition it will be reached.